# Vector subscript out of range - 2D vector within class constructor initialisation

Tags: c++, class, vector, range, subscript

I am doing a project which creates an isosceles triangle from base and side inputs. I then need to calculate the coordinates and store them in some use-able way. What I have tried to do is create a 2D vector of vertices - so an array of 3 coords each with an array of two dimensions (x and y values). When I try to access the values (eg. for translation) I get a runtime error:  vector subscript out of range...

code:

private:

```
double base, side;
vector<double> coordA, coordB, coordC;
vector<vector<double> > vertex;
```

public:

```
isoTri() : base(0), side(0), coordA(0), coordB(0), coordC(0) {}
isoTri(double base_in, double side_in) : base(base_in), side(side_in)
{
    coordA.push_back(0); coordA.push_back(0); //bottom left corner at origin
    coordB.push_back(base2); coordB.push_back(height); //top corner
    coordC.push_back(base); coordC.push_back(0); //bottom right corner
    vector<vector<double> > vertex{ 3 };
    vertex[0] = { coordA }; vertex[1] = { coordB }; vertex[2] = { coordC }; //vector of coordinates
    }
~isoTri() {}

void translate(double dx, double dy){

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            vertex[i][0] = vertex[i][0] + dx;
            vertex[j][1] = vertex[j][1] + dy;
        }
    }
}; `
```

Comment: did you debug your program statement by statement?

Answer (score 3):

`vector<vector<double> > vertex{ 3 };`, is declaring a new local variable named `vertex`, which has nothing to do with the member variable `vertex`. It remains empty. You could:

```
isoTri(double base_in, double side_in) : base(base_in), side(side_in)
{
    coordA.push_back(0); coordA.push_back(0); //bottom left corner at origin
    coordB.push_back(base2); coordB.push_back(height); //top corner
    coordC.push_back(base); coordC.push_back(0); //bottom right corner
    vertex.push_back(coordA); 
    vertex.push_back(coordB); 
    vertex.push_back(coordC);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: @FergusFrank Coffee time. Good luck. :)